# Can we create a custom uri to call different controller method functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have bee going through various [MVC tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and have also made a simple one.
All of them only seem to address two kinds of uri to use. What if we want to use something other than 'controller' and 'id'?

also how does it know which function is being called? the uri is `/api/products` but the function that returns value is `public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()`

Below is an example of a controller

```
using ProductsApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ProductsApp.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[] 
        { 
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
}
```

In this case I can only call the two functions in my web browser

[image]

I wish to call uri that is somthing along the line of

> /api/products/foo

Comment: are u aware that you are writing an api and not web application?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is different than WebForms, because it does convention over configuration. If you do custom routing, you're moving away from this convention, which is not recommended in some cases. In any case, MVC's default convention is /[ControllerClass-"Controller"]/FunctionName/FunctionParameterValue or /[ControllerClass-"Controller"]/FunctionName?FunctionParameter=FunctionParameterValue. Is there a reason you're using custom routing? A lot of people do it with a valid reason. Just make sure that your reason is justifiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Route Prefixes` and `Route` attributes to acceive it, like below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("foo")]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts(){}
}
```

Then you can call `/api/products/foo` or `/api/products`, both of them give you same result.

For more details about Web Api `Attribute Routing`, take a look at the following link:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 2):

You should about Routing in ASP.NET MVC. 
Routing enables you to set your custom rules of defining which URLs should point to which actions (and controllers).

You can read more about routing e.g. here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }
```

to

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> Foo()
    {
        return products;
    }
```